# "debuild -S" changes debian/control

Tags: debian, package-management

I'm trying to modify an [nvidia-related package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/nvidia-319-updates) from the Ubuntu Saucy repositories. I change the Build-Depends: line, I run `debuild -S` to generate a source upload for my PPA, and... surprise, the Build-Depends line in debian/control reverts to the original. How is this possible and how do I prevent this insanity? I mean, in general, how can a package affect the input to its build process?

This is similar to `gcc -o prog prog.c` being able to change prog.c. I don't know why Debian made source building so Turing complete -- or why anyone would take advantage of such misguided features.

```
dget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/n/nvidia-graphics-drivers-319-updates/nvidia-graphics-drivers-319-updates_319.60-0ubuntu1.dsc
dpkg-source -x nvidia-graphics-drivers-319-updates_319.60-0ubuntu1.dsc
# change the Build-Depends line
perl -pi.bak -e 's/(xserver-xorg-dev)/xserver-xorg-dev-lts-raring | $1/' debian/control
cp debian/control /tmp
debuild -S
diff debian/control /tmp/control # proving debuild changed debian/control
```

Comment: Can you list the exact commands you used to get to that point? For example, did you use `apt-get source` to download the sources?

Comment: Repro steps added to OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a `control.in` file at 
`nvidia-graphics-drivers-319-updates-319.60/debian/templates/control.in`. I assume the `control` file is regenerated from this file, though I've not checked this carefully. I've run into such situations before, usually with more complex packaging. I suggest altering that file instead of the `control` file.

Comment: Let's see if that works, thanks. If so, this is not such a new mechanism as I thought.